# How to use if else blocks to decide style in Razor?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I know how to format css syle of an element in Razor with given condition only by using ternary operator, as in the following example:

```
<div style="@(Model.Condition ? "float:left" : "float:right")">
```

But I got a more complex decision block and I should be nesting 2 ternary operators, which is not a really good practice. I have tried this way:

```
<div style="@{
          if (Model.Condition)
          {
               "float:left"
          }
          else
          {
               "float:right"
          }
}">
```

and it is showing error:

> ; expected

after the strings inside `if-else` block, and if I add `;` it is still giving an error like the following

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Is there a way to do this using `if-else` blocks?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can always declare a local variable at the beginning of the View:

```
@{
   var yourStyle = "";
   if(Model.Condition)
   {
       yourStyle = "float:left;";
   }
   else
   {
       yourStyle = "float:right;";
      //any other conditions and logic
   }
}
```

and then just use it in your div:

```
<div style="@yourStyle">
```

Comment: Why didn't I considered this? Thank you!

Comment: Is it okay to use such, but like `yourStyle = "style = \"float:left;\""`?